Not able to use the union types on graphql using apollo client
I have a query that uses union types inside it.
sample query
person {
      ... on jedi{
        id
        lightsaber
      }
      ... on mandalorian{
        id
        beskar
      }
    }

when I try to use useQuery from apolloClient it is returning the person object with empty brackets [{},{}] but when using fetch() it is returning [{id:232, lightsaber:green},{id:242, beskar: old}]
I tried specifying the union type in the apollo client
const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: concat(authMiddleware, httpLink),
  cache: new InMemoryCache({
    addTypename: false,
    possibleTypes:{PersonUnion:['jedi','mandalorian']}
  }),
})

it is not returning the any properties inside the object just an empty object {}
Edit: here is the useQuery
const {data:QueryData} = useQuery<PersonQuery>(GET_PERSON)

The client code you've provided is only the GraphQL connection and cache configuration - you haven't provided the query you're using. Can you please provide the useQuery hook you're executing?

Sorry I have added it now. @CharlieStanard
